# Screen resolution is low in tty with fglrx?

Tags: graphics, fglrx, tty

My screen resolution is 1600x900p normally. Without specific graphic drivers it 900p in GRUB and ttys, too. If i install fglrx as driver it is set to 640x480p when i start a tty, and the widescreen causes big "pulled" letters on my screen. Does Anyone know how to fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because fglrx (the proprietary AMD Radeon device driver) does not support Kernel-Mode Setting (KMS).

In the GRUB (boot loader) configuration file located in `/etc/default/grub` there is a setting called GRUB_GFXMODE you can set it to `GRUB_GFXMODE=1200x900`. Then you need to run `sudo update-grub2`.

Run `vbeinfo` in GRUB to see which graphics modes your graphics card supports.